# “puked” vs. “vomited”

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

> You ***puked*** a lot last night.
>
> You ***vomited*** a lot last night.

Which verb is more suitable for stating that a baby vomited milk?

Comment: For these particular sentences (ignoring the context of a baby) they should be you puked and you vomited

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would not say either about a baby.

I would say:

> Our baby **spits up** milk.
>   Our baby was **spitting up** milk last night.   (AmE)

*Puke* is a crude word for *vomit*, so I don't think you would want to use that for an innocent baby.

A baby that does not have an illness probably is not vomiting, but has colic or gas instead.

Comment: Our baby was spitting up milk last night. 
Why we use continuous tense in this sentence?

Comment: Because @user73963 it indicates that the baby was spitting up milk on a frequent basis during that night, that it was not just once or twice.

Comment: I don't think there'd be any objection to saying that a baby puked in British English. Nobody would interpret it as any kind of moral judgement -- everyone knows that babies often puke and make other kinds of unpleasant mess.

Comment: This is incorrect. In a biological sense, to "spit" is to forcibly eject something (usually saliva) that is present in the mouth. In this instance, the milk is being produced form the stomach / gut. "Vomit" means to eject something from the stomach. Its definition does not include reference to an illness.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that "Spit up" is AFAIK, uncommon outside of the US.

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest Everyday English is often biologically incorrect but that doesn't make it wrong as language. For example, almost everything (except hazelnuts and chestnuts) that we call a "nut" isn't actually a nut, biologically speaking.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, the OP seems to be talking about possetting, which isn't actually the same thing as puking/vomiting. http://www.webmd.boots.com/children/baby/guide/baby-possetting-reflux-vomiting

Comment: `spitting up` is American English. In British English we use the word `possetting` (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/posset) or a phrase such as `bringing up` or `bringing back` some milk. Referring to vomiting or puking suggests illness which may not be appropriate when describing a post feed baby.

Answer (score 13):

Neither verb is the correct past tense.
The sentences should be
You puked(vomited) a lot last night.

There are many other choices.
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vomit

To Spit Up or Regurgitate are more appropriate synonyms.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard somebody say that their baby regurgitated. Sure, it's a correct word but it's not the sort of thing you'd say in everyday speech.

Comment: +1 Sorry for doubting regurgitate! You were right = " verb (possets, possetting, possetted)
[no object]  
(Of a baby) ***regurgitate** curdled milk*: "**bless its little heart, it’s possetting again**""

Comment: Still agree with @DavidRicherby regarding everyday speech.

Answer (score 5):

In British English neither, use 'posset' instead because

- 'vomit' is disgusting,
- 'puke' is vulgar / slang,
- neither really describes the milk-returned-to-sender phenomenon which occurs with small babies, it's different to adult vomiting, and it doesn't necessarily indicate that they're ill ( http://www.webmd.boots.com/children/baby/guide/baby-possetting-reflux-vomiting ).

> VERB (possets, possetting, possetted)
>
> **(Of a baby) regurgitate curdled milk**
>
> *"bless its little heart, it’s possetting again"*
>
> *"From time to time the baby belched and possetted back a small quantity of milk."*
>
> *"Of course, Freddie pulled my hair and possetted onto it as soon as I got home again!"*

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/posset

NB "To be sick" or to "sick up" is also used as a more polite synonym for 'puke' or 'vomit' in British English.

'Regurgitation' is also sometimes used about babies e.g. *Some babies bring up more milk than others during or just after a feed. This is sometimes called ‘possetting’ or ‘regurgitation’ or ‘reflux’.* http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/pregnancy-and-baby/pages/bottle-feeding-advice.aspx

So say: "**The baby was possetting a lot last night**".

("The baby possetted a lot last night" would also be ok, "was possetting a lot last night" is better if it happened over a longish period of time).

Comment: This must be strictly British English, because I have never heard the term "posset" before (and Chrome spel chek doesn't believe it's a word, either). Also, it can also be a milk-based dessert? Ugh.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar "Lemon posset with fennel biscotti" http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/lemon_posset_with_fennel_86459 :)

Comment: Yeah, that looks like something a baby posseted.

Comment: For my part (british, no children) I have never heard the word possetting and I would probably personally say puking or vomitting.  I'm not sure what your point is that "'vomit' is disgusting". I find it quite disgusting when a baby regurgitates its food as well so this doesn't seem to be a good reason not to use vomit. And I'd personally describe puking as slang and not vulgar but that's probably a less important distinction. I will say that parents tend to have very different views than non-parents so it may be that parents are less inclined towards the terms used for adults.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, it's a parent thing, e.g. see [all these mumsnet threads about possetting](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=site:mumsnet.com+possetting) (and that's just one website). Only babies posset. 

Re vomit, the point is that possetting is actually different to vomitting, e.g. [one author](http://salamander-teamotoole.blogspot.co.uk/2011_02_01_archive.html) says "Very little babies tend to 'posset' a lot - in other words, they bring up little burps of milk after they have been fed." 

I find it a lot less disgusting than vomit but obviously that's subjective - YMMV.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I'm British with no kids and have also never heard that term before either.

Comment: @AE: Cool. I mainly wanted to make clear that even though it is official British English it may not be widely understood

Comment: @Chris: yeah, that's true. Parents will probably understand it as will medical professionals, but 'civilians' won't necessarily. ;)

Answer (score 2):

" Throws up" is better than "pukes" when referring a baby bringing out milk when unwell.

Comment: True, however the OP was asking specifically about "last night" so the tense is wrong

Comment: Puking, vomiting, throwing up - I've heard all three used to refer to a baby being sick in the last month!

Answer (score 2):

```
All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players.
They have their exits and their entrances,
And one man in his time plays many parts,
His acts being seven ages. At first the infant,
Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms.
```

I couldn't resist.

Comment: P.S. In my dialect (American English, northeast, Irish-influenced), babies "spit up". Also the noun, "spit-up". "There's some spit-up on the baby's bib."

Comment: Your answer is a comment and your comment is an answer!

Comment: I paint outside the lines, what can I say.